# How come both console.log() execute when there is a condition to prevent such a thing from happening?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to automate the MySQL server startup once I start my application with the following code:

```js
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

let check = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  exec('mysql-ctl status', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error)
      reject(error);
    else
      resolve(stderr);
  })
);

let start = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  exec('mysql-ctl start', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error)
      reject(error);
    else
      resolve(console.log("MySQL server is up!"));
  })
);

async function check_status() {
  return await check;
}

async function start_server(status) {
  if (status.trim() == 'MySQL is stopped') {
    console.log("Starting MySQL server...");
    await start;
  } else console.log("MySQL server was up...");
}

module.exports = async function() {
  check_status()
    .then((status) => start_server(status))
    .catch((error) => console.log("Error: " + error));
};
```

However, if the server is already up, I get the following output:

```js
App Started. Listening on PORT 8080
MySQL server was up...
MySQL server is up!
```

How come both console.log() are executing when there is a condition to prevent precisely that?

Comment: Because your creating a promise that always runs, no matter what.  IOW: This bit of code is executed always -> `let start = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>`

Comment: @Keith Thanks! Then how do I construct a promise to run it later? Like so: `function start() { return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {}) }` ?

Comment: Just make `start` into a function that returns a promise.. eg.. `function start() { return new Promise......`  , and then call  `await start()`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `new Promise(resolve, reject => ())` you are starting execution of function given to promise. That function is executed asynchronously.

So in your case you start checking if MySQL is running and next you start script for starting MySQL, but before check is finished.

```
module.exports = async function() {
  check_status()
    .then((status) => start_server(status))
    .catch((error) => console.log("Error: " + error));
};
```

When this function is executed you are just awaiting result from `check` in `check_status()`. But that check was started when `check` variable is created.

Result of this is in your `then` method => `MySQL server is up!`. When `check` is being executed start is also being executed and because MySQL server is not started you are getting `Starting MySQL server...`